# Distributed query with Hibernate multi-tenancy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, multi-tenant

I am using [Hibernate's multi-tenancy](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch16.html) feature via JPA, with a [database per tenant strategy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx). One of my requirements is to be able to run a query against a table that exists in each database but obviously with different data. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Nope. this is not possible because when hibernate runs queries it is already initialized with a connection. MT support in Hibernate is basically done a little "outside of Hibernate" itself. It's kind of  feeding hibernate with a proper connection and when it's fed :) it's bound to that connection.

If you need cross-tenant queries you might want to reconsider multitenancy or change JPA provider to the one that support "shared schema approach" e.g. EclipseLink. With shared shema approach you have two choices:

1. run native query agains table containing mt-aware entities
2. create additional entity - dont mark it as multitenant - map it to the table containing mt-ware entities and run JPQL query in standard manner

Comment: Hi Tomasz. Thanks for you reply. I can't go with a shared schema approach because I plan to move the data across physical servers as the load increases.

Comment: there might a way out of this: iterate over tenants and for each tenant: 1. set it as current tenant, 2. start transaction, 3. execute your query and 4. end transaction. I haven't tested that with Hibernate, but with EclipseLink I was able to query againts tenant-own-data.

Comment: Yes that's what I'll end up doing if I don't find a more elegant solution. Thanks for your help.